# Ajuda com validação em javascript de campos?

Tags: javascript, html, validação

Amigos o que está acontecendo é que está passando espaços e números repetidos, não sei mais o que fazer :P

```html
<form name="form" id="form" action="passo_01.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validasucesso()">

<td bgcolor="#F7F7F7" ><input name="table1" type="text" id="table1" lang="1" onKeyUp="javascript:pulacampo('table1','table2');" size="3" maxlength="4" onKeyPress="return SomenteNumero(event)" autofocus /></td>
```

```js
function IsNumeric(){
      myForm = document.getElementById("form");
      var myArray=[];
      for(i=0;i<myForm.elements.length;i++){
       if(myForm.elements[i].type=='number'){
        myArray[myArray.length]=myForm.elements[i].value;
       }
      }
      myArray.sort();
      for(i=0;i<myArray.length-1;i++){
       if(myArray[i]==myArray[i+1]){
        alert('Chaves repitidas no formulário!');
        selectkey(myArray[i]);
        return false;
        break;
        exit;
       }
      }
      return true;
}

function validasucesso(){
 var i;
 var value;
 for (i = 1;i <=70;i ++) {
    eval("value = document.form.table" + i + ".value");
     if (value.length < 4) {
   alert("Cartão de segurança inválido, verifique os dígitos corretamente."); 
   eval("document.form.table" + i +".focus()");
   return false;
  }  
  
  if (IsNumeric(value)) {
  }
  else
  {
   alert("Cartão de segurança inválido, verifique os dígitos corretamente."); 
   eval("document.form.table" + i +".focus()");
   return false;
  }
 }
  for (i = 1;i <=70;i ++) {
     eval("value = document.form.table" + i + ".value");
     eval("document.form.table" + i + ".value = value");
  } 
}
```

Comment: O código postado está sem condições de teste! Quem é SomenteNumero quem é pulacampo

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo são validações que estão funcionando, posso postar aqui pra você !

Comment: function SomenteNumero(e){
    var tecla=(window.event)?event.keyCode:e.which;
    if((tecla > 47 && tecla < 58)) return true;
    else{
    if (tecla != 8) return false;
    else return true;
    }
}

function pulacampo(idobj, idproximo)
{
var str = new String(document.getElementById(idobj).value);
var mx = new Number(document.getElementById(idobj).maxLength);
if (str.length == mx)
{
document.getElementById(idproximo).focus();
}
}

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(function(){
      $('#smesp').bind('input', function(){
        $(this).val(function(_, v){
         return v.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        });
      });
    $('#smesp').bind('input', function(){
        $(this).val(function(_, v){
         return v.replace('99', '9');
        });
      });      
    $('#smesp').bind('input', function(){
        $(this).val(function(_, v){
         return v.replace('88', '8');
        });
      });      
    $('#smesp').bind('input', function(){
        $(this).val(function(_, v){
         return v.replace('77', '7');
        });
      });      
    $('#smesp').bind('input', function(){
        $(this).val(function(_, v){
         return v.replace('66', '6');
        });
      });      
    $('#smesp').bind('input', function(){
        $(this).val(function(_, v){
         return v.replace('55', '5');
        });
      });      
    $('#smesp').bind('input', function(){
        $(this).val(function(_, v){
         return v.replace('44', '4');
        });
      });      
    $('#smesp').bind('input', function(){
        $(this).val(function(_, v){
         return v.replace('33', '3');
        });
      });      
    $('#smesp').bind('input', function(){
        $(this).val(function(_, v){
         return v.replace('22', '2');
        });
      });      
    $('#smesp').bind('input', function(){
        $(this).val(function(_, v){
         return v.replace('11', '1');
        });
      });      
    $('#smesp').bind('input', function(){
        $(this).val(function(_, v){
         return v.replace('00', '0');
        });
      });      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="smesp"></textarea>
```

Comment: ele está bloqueando, só não esta bloqueando os números repetidos!

Comment: Calma, estou pensando aqui.

Comment: Pronto. Acho que ficou simples de ler.

Comment: são 4 digitos cada campo, são 50 campos, o que eu não queria é que o cara digitasse 50 campos 0000 entendeu...

Comment: Eu fiz o que você disse na pergunta (não deixa passar espaços e números repetidos). Você deve escrever com bastante detalhes a sua pergunta. Editando ela se for preciso.

Comment: Entendi, e aí como eu monto ? Em todos os campos o id aí ?

Comment: Você deverá criar outra pergunta amigo, sendo mais específico no que quer. Outras pessoas no futuro consultarão este site em busca do mesmo problema que você está passando, por isso temos que manter tudo organizado por aqui.